# Python - count the number of letter U's and return the line that contains them

Tags: python, count

My professor wants us to create a program that will allow multiple lines of input from a user and determine which line has the most amount of the letter U. We then need to print the count and the line.
Example of input:

```
This u is u an u example u line.
This u is another.
Example u line u.
```

Example of output:

```
Line with the most U's: 4
This u is u an u exammple u line.
```

I have this so far for the count but I am completely stuck on how to get it to go line by line.

```py
#input line was provided by professor - not needed
def count_letter_u(line):
  count = 0
  for ch in line:
    if ch == 'u':
      count += 1
  return count
```

Comment: Use a second `for` loop to iterate over each line.

Comment: Looks like this function ```count_letter_u``` is supposed to do only one thing i.e. count the number of ```u```. I don't see the rest of the code so I assume you need another function with this line ```for line in lines:``` calling ```count_letter_u``` at each iteration.

Comment: Also does a ```u``` inside of a word like ```understand``` or ```quick``` counts ?

Comment: There is a def(main) at the bottom of the code where the count_letter_u function gets called on and asks for the users input. And yes, all U's whether imbedded in a word or not count.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you are getting multiple lines as input so I wrote my own way of getting multiple lines as input. Enter the lines and press `ctrl+z` and then `Enter` to stop taking input, these lines will get saved in `contents` list. The program loops through the list and appends the sentence as key and "u" count as the value in a dict. Then the max value with its respective key is printed.

```
print("Enter your content, Ctrl+D and Enter to save it.") # Ctrl+Z if on windows
contents = [] # list of sentences
dict = {}
while True: 
    try: 
        line = input() 
    except EOFError: 
        break 
    contents.append(line) # append each line to contents

def count_letter_u(line): # no of "u" in a line
  count = 0
  for ch in line:
    if ch == 'u':
      count += 1
  return count

for sentence in contents:
  dict[sentence] = count_letter_u(sentence) # add sentence, count to dict

max = max(zip(dict.values(), dict.keys()))[1] # max value

print(f"Line with the most U's: {dict.get(max)}, {max}")
```

**Output**

```
Enter your content, Ctrl-D and Enter to save it.
This u is u an u example u line.
This u is another.
Example u line u.
Line with the most U's: 4, This u is u an u example u line.
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
input_string = "This u is u an u example u line.\nThis u is another.\nExample u line u."
lines = input_string.splitlines()  #splitting the string in lines

most_u = -1                        # most 'U' count (since a line may have 0 'U' but not -1 so ) will be greater)
index_with_most_u = -1             # index (number) of line which has most 'U'

def count_letter_u(line):
  count = 0
  for ch in line:
    if ch == 'u':
      count += 1
  return count

for index,line in enumerate(lines):
    if most_u < count_letter_u(line): # If we find greater number of U till this point we update the most_u and line number
        most_u = count_letter_u(line)
        index_with_most_u = index
        
print("Line with the most U's:" + str(most_u))
print(lines[index_with_most_u])
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the users input and store it into an empty array.
Then loop through the characters inside the each array element and check for U's using the `count()` function [str.count(sub[, start[, end]]](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.count).

Create a dictionary from the two arrays and find the max value of the number of Us and print the corresponding line.

```
def user_lines():
    line = []
    u_input = 0
    while u_input != 'stop':
        # Loops through the length of the line array
        u_input = input('Enter your line: ')
        if u_input == 'stop':
            break
        # Append the user input to the line array
        line.append(u_input)
        print(line)

    word_count = []
    for word in line:
        # Appends the amount of Us found inside the word
        word_count.append(word.count('u'))

    # Zipping the u_array and word_count arrays together to create a dictionary
    # This associates the words with the number of U's inside
    mapping = dict(zip(line, word_count))

    # Finds the biggest number of Us in
    new_val = mapping.values()
    maximum_val = max(new_val)

    # Finds the key associated with the max value
    key_max = max(zip(mapping.values(), mapping.keys()))[1]
    print('The line with the most Us are:', key_max, 'with', maximum_val)

user_lines()
```